# Can we use HOC to wrap functional components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a react app to demonstrate the working of HOC on functional components. I've two scenarios where a button and a heading display the number of clicks performed on the button and mouseovers on the heading with the same code internally. However, I get the error as mentioned. The error explains that the hook rule is broken. I could see that using hooks inside non-functional components is the incorrect way. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to use HOC that wraps functional components. Also, if it is possible to wrap functional components inside a HOC, then where do I change my code?

Here is my HOC code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Count = (Component) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const incrementHandler = (e) => {
    setCount((prevState) => {
      return prevState + 1;
    });
  };
  return <Component count={count} incrementHandler={incrementHandler} />;
};

export default Count;
```

Here is my ClickCounter component

```
import React from "react";
import Count from "../HOC/CountHOC";

const ClickCounter = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.incrementHandler}>
        Clicked {props.count} times
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Count(ClickCounter);
```

Here is my HoverCounter code

```
import React from "react";
import Count from "../HOC/CountHOC";

const HoverCounter = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onMouseOver={props.incrementHandler}>Hovered {props.count} times</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Count(HoverCounter);
```

Comment: @RajThakar - That's not the correct way to use a HOC, and would fail if it didn't happen to be in a function component. What happens there is the function you've imported as `HOC` is simply *called* during the render of the function component it's in, so the `useState` calls create state members in the function you called `HOC` from. It happens to work in that case, but won't in the general case.

Comment: yes, you are correct @T.J.Crowder. my code won't work for the class component, just now verified. Sorry for the inconvenience .

Comment: @RajThakar - No worries. :-) I suggest removing the comment, though, since it might mislead others in the future. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap function components just like you can wrap `class` components; the HOC doesn't know or care which kind you give it. If you look at the examples of HOCs in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), you'll notice that they all *return functions* (in the case of that page, constructor functions):

> ```
> // This function takes a component...
> function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
>   // ...and returns another component...
>   return class extends React.Component {
>     // ...
>   };
> }
> ```

The result of a `class` expression is the constructor function of the class. A HOC function returns the new wrapper component it builds. Your function returns the result of `React.createElement` instead.

You need to **return** the enhanced component (whether a function or `class` component), rather than writing the HOC function itself as a component:

```
const withCount = (Component) => {
    return function(props) {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        const incrementHandler = (e) => {
            setCount((prevState) => {
                return prevState + 1;
            });
        };
        return <Component {...props} count={count} incrementHandler={incrementHandler} />;
    };
};
```

The changes I made there are:

- Changed `Count` to `withCount`, since it's not a (simple) component, it's a HOC.
- Had it return the enhanced component.
- Had the enhanced component accept props that it passes along to the wrapped component.

Live Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const withCount = (Component) => {
    return function(props) {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        const incrementHandler = (e) => {
            setCount((prevState) => {
                return prevState + 1;
            });
        };
        return <Component {...props} count={count} incrementHandler={incrementHandler} />;
    };
};

const ClickCounter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.incrementHandler}>
                Clicked {props.count} times
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

const EnhancedClickCounter = withCount(ClickCounter);

ReactDOM.render(<EnhancedClickCounter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou @T.J. Crowder. Your code worked!! And thanks again for the explanation